# Where did they get the background music for "The Magic Roundabout"?

Tags: soundtrack, the-magic-roundabout

In pretty much every episode of the original series of *The Magic Roundabout*, there was some jazzy background music. For example, [this one](https://youtu.be/c3DcChXNyYQ?t=110) (from 1:50 and more from 3:27), [this one](https://youtu.be/_aBMn1NfXdc?t=125) (from 2:05) and [this one](https://youtu.be/ivaR5dK9tMg?t=66) (from 1:06 and 3:12).

Those are all reasonable pieces of music, but many episodes (which I can't find online, but such as the one where Brian and Dylan form a band, and Dougal ends up joining in, playing some pretty discordant "music", or the one where Mr MacHenry has "a sort of university of the air" where he teaches birds to sing) featured some fairly weird music that didn't sound like the sort of thing anyone would write for pleasure!

I just found [this link](https://www.discogs.com/Eric-Thompson-Magic-Roundabout/release/9123413), which shows the cassette we had which contained the two episodes I mentioned above ("Dougal The Musician" and "Birds", respectively). If anyone has this cassette, they'll know what I mean!

Anyone know where they got this music? Was it pre-existing, or did the BBC write it specially?

The latter seems unlikely, as (as far as I remember), when the BBC bought the original series, the French company who sold it to them did not include the scripts, and wanted extra money for those. Eric Thomson, unable to understand the French, turned the sound down and wrote his own scripts. It seems unlikely that the French would have supplied them with the music separately (which it needed to be, as it was often behind dialogue) as part of the price, and then tried to charge them extra for the scripts. This of course is not a proof, merely my speculation, so feel free to correct me if you know better.

Either way, does this music exist anywhere?

Comment: idk how certain the info is, but discogs has it listed - https://www.discogs.com/Eric-Thompson-Magic-Roundabout/release/1037906 wikipedia has some info too - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Roundabout#Records It all feels a bit vague, so idk if it makes an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the link, but it's basically the same as the one I added in my update, albeit for a different version. Like you said, it's vague.